# How do I send data as a response from Node.js server to AJAX client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, server

So I'm calling this function to send data about an HTML element as an object:

```
function postItem(input) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    data: input,
    success: function(message) {
      Hconsole.log('got data back');
      var m = message;
      alert(m);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('text status ' + textstatus + ', err ' + errorThrown);
    }
  })
}
```

And the server is to compare the input object and an already stored object, and to respond with whether they're the same or not:

```
app.post('/', (req, resp) => {
  var eObjClient = req.body;

  //somehow get data from database, the following is dummy data
  var eObjServer = {
    type: 'I',
    text: '',
    width: '70',
    height: '80',
    href: '',
    color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    class: 'icon-big icon ion-ios-analytics-outline'
  };

  /*
  Object.keys(eObjClient).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key + ": " + eObjClient[key]);
  });
  */

  if (isSimilar(eObjClient, eObjServer)) {
    console.log('step working');
    resp.send('step working');
  } else {
    console.log('broken');
    resp.send('broken');
  }
  resp.end();
});
```

Currently the server gets the data and does the calculations fine, but the error message on the client side is always invoked and I don't know why. Additionally, I keep getting this error on the client side console if it helps:

> "Failed to load http://localhost:8080/: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I'm using the libraries *Express.js* and *body-parser*. I'm a beginner to server stuff, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also shouldn't call `res.end()` after `res.send()` at all, as the latter calls the former under the hood and you'll get errors for calling it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your client and server are cross domain and so the browser is blocking it.

you could try in your Node.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

However, it is important to note that it will allow any connection and should not be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop in CORS middleware and your client AJAX request should function properly. You can use this library: https://github.com/expressjs/cors in the following way:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. One question though, would this be safe to use in production?

Answer (score -1):

You should change your logic with:

```
    let message = '';

    if(isSimilar(eObjClient, eObjServer)) {
      console.log('step working');
      message = 'step working';
    }
    else {
      console.log('broken');
      message = 'broken';
    }
    resp.status(200).send(message);
```

For your CORS problem I would recommend setting the appropiate headers or use [cors library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner to this; how would I set headers or use cors? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure, the headers can be set in your response like Lady_A's answer, before your logic. Basically it is a security method to block other users from using you app. If you use cors npm package, just follow installation instructions and add in your `app.js` this line to set it as middleware: `app.use(cors())`